# Java get List of parameter in a List of Objects

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have an easy question, but i didn't know how to search about it...

Let's say I have a List of objects, List, and MyObject is something like this:

```
List<MyObject> mo;


class MyObject{
      private SecondObject so;
    }

    class SecondObject{
      private String sp;

    }
```

I want to retrieve the list of the string parameter in the List of MyObject, and the only way I managed is to loop on the List...

Is there a smarter/faster way?

thank you, bye!!

Comment: post the code where you loop it.

Comment: I don't see any list in your code.

Comment: with only this much information, we can only say "bbye!"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP's minimum effort of solving.

Comment: @Ruchira off-topic means that the question is not related with the genaral topics which concerns the SO. This question is on-topic BUT inappropriate to get any answer, unacceptable for minimal effort etc but not off-topic.

Comment: @Eypros Under minimum effort of OP we can close giving reason as off-topic

Comment: I am just saying that it's a bad choice of adjective. That's all. The point remain that the question has serious issues.

Comment: We can help with if you create a minimal example. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

using java 8, you can do the following:

```
List<MyObject> myObjectList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
...
List<String> spList = myObjectList.stream().map(mo -> mo.getSo().getSp()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, probably you should use a **`Map<String, Object>`**, where you can access to element by **key** (no loop needed).
You have to initialize the map with the elements of your list: SecondObject.sp as **key**, MyObject as **object**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Guava library. In particular [`Iterables.transform()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#transform(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) method.

Here's an example:

```
List<MyObject> list = ...
Iterable<String> strings = Iterables.transform(list,
                        new Function<MyObject, String>() {
                            @Override
                            public String apply(MyObject obj) {
                                return obj.getSecondObject().getSp();
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no direct way of doing it. But you can create your own Custom List.

```
public class CustomList implements List<MyObject> {

    private List<SecondObject> list = new ArrayList<SecondObject>();
    private List<MyObject> listMy = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

    public List<SecondObject> getSecondList(){
         return list;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, MyObject element) {
        listMy.add(index, element);
        list.add(index, element.sp);
    }

....... // Override other methods also

}
```

Now you can use getSecondList() to get the SecondObjectList. It will be faster than enumeration.

Note: You have to override other methods in the List interface also according to your requirement.